# Import Issue with a csv file into SQL Server 2008 table

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-import-wizard

I'm using SQL Server Import and Export wizard to import data from a csv file to append to my already existing SQL Server table.

So, to append data from a csv file to my SQL Server table, in `Choose a Data Source` window, I'm making sure that each column in my csv data source has equivalent data type as that of my SQL Server table columns.

However, I always end up getting error while doing import.

> *Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data
>   conversion for column "Maturity(Hours)" returned status value 2 and status
>   text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of
>   data.".  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)*
>
> *Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "output column "Maturity
>   (Hours)" (42)" failed because error code 0xC0209084 occurred, and the
>   error row disposition on "output column "Maturity(Hours)" (42)" specifies
>   failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the
>   specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this
>   with more information about the failure.  (SQL Server Import and
>   Export Wizard)*

My SQL Server table has `Maturity` (hours) as `int` datatype.

For my csv file, in SQL Server Export/Import wizard, I'm selecting `DT_I4` for `Maturity` (hours), which is equivalent to int data type in SQL Server. Still I couldn't get rid of that error for the past 3 hours.

Any clue on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: do all the field have the same length too apart from the datatype?

Comment: Hi Ron, Thanks for your comment. Apaprt from ensuring field size for each string field on SQL end and csv file, how do I ensure the field size for int columns?

Comment: I am not sure about the values in your csv file and if the column has to be strictly int. I would try by changing the column type to be numeric and specify the precision.

Comment: My SQL table has int data type for Maturity (Hours) field. As per your suggestion, In import wizard, I changed the data type in source csv as DT_Numeric and set DataPrecision. However, i get the same error. :(

Comment: Can you have the data type numeric in SQL too?

Comment: The table I have in SQL is also imported from a MS Access db table, and MS Access table has int data type for Maturity (Hours) field. When I first imported Access table to SQl server, the data type supported in SQL showed SQL data types such as int, smallint, bigint. Since its int to int conversion, I picked int for SQL Maturity (Hours) field as well. Does SQL even support Numeric data type?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 Has a neumeric data type - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: Ron's approach should have worked.  Nemo, I had a recent problem with exactly the same field type and CSV source.  It turns out that several of the values in the field I thought contained only integers actually contained characters.  Open your CSV file in Excel and see if you have the same issue.

Comment: I checked my CSV file in Excel and I see that my Maturity (Hours) field has data in ranging from 0 to 11465 and in Excel's Home tab, for that field, its General type. I tried Ron's suggestion- tried having decimal data type for SQl table as numeric is equivalent to decimal. So I set decimal(5,0) for SQL table and while importing csv, I set the field type as DT_NUMERIC with DataPrecision 5. Still same error.

Comment: I suggest you divide and conquer your CSV file and find the data row with the error. You'll probably find some bad data with a number that is too large to fit into INT4

Comment: 1. Just for testing, let SSIS create a table. This can be done by clicking on the "New" button next to the Table field in the OleDB Destination. Compare this table structure with yours.

Comment: 2. Redirect the error rows to a text file, instead of splitting your source file.

Comment: Thanks Anoop for your i/p. I will spend more time on testing as you suggested and let u know how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a look in the csv file if  any field has any commas (in case if you used comma as  column separator or double quotes (in case if you used double quotes as text qualifier). Your problem should come under the above 2 scenarios.

Note: I put this as answer as I could not comment on your question.

Comment: I used double quote as a text qualifier and on tracing the huge amount of data by divide and conquer method, I found few rows have double quotes. Thanks for your generic answer.

Comment: Can you please tell me how did you handle this error? did you just skipped those records or you did any other fix?

Comment: I used to get csv files from one of my teams and I had a job to import that to my sql table. I requested my team to send me clean data. I want the team to be accountable to give me th ecorrect source. :)